# How to disable time in ajax time selector

Tags: c#, asp.net, timespan, time-select

Please suggest how to hide time slot in ajax `TimeSelector`. I want to set the time between 9:00 pm to 6:00 am

I am already tired by setting `EndTime` and `StartTime` to the `TimeSelector`

Here is my time selector

```
<cc1:TimeSelector ID="TimeSelector2" runat="server" SelectedTimeFormat="Twelve"   StartTime="09:00:00:PM" EndTime ="06:00:00:AM" >
</cc1:TimeSelector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a *very old* component library, `MKB.TimePicker` by Michael K Bell. `TimeSelector` is part of this library.  It is no longer maintained.

The only references left anywhere for this are in archival links:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20090211034750/http://www.asp.net/community/control-gallery/Item.aspx?i=3221
- https://web.archive.org/web/20111030161022/http://www.michaelkbell.com/timepicker/
- https://searchcode.com/file/9968160/MKB/TimePicker/TimeSelector.cs

As far as I can tell from the above links, the functionality you're looking for does not exist in this control.  There are no `StartTime` or `EndTime` properties defined.

I recommend finding a different control - one that is actively supported.